# Imageview attributes lost after setting animation

Tags: android, animation, background-image

I am trying to set frame animation to Imageview.

```
imageAnim =  (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderCards);
imageAnim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_switcher_anim);
imageAnim.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageAnim.getBackground();
anim.start();
```

All the Image view attributes like height width, scale type are lost. 
I understood this happens because of setting animation as background resource and images will be displayed without scaletype.

I see two possibilities
Is there a way to set animation without setting it as background to avoid this problem ?
OR
Can the attributes like height width etc be set for image background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageAnim.invalidateDrawable(anim);
```

this will redraw the image view.

Comment: NO ... it doesnt help .. it actually removes the animation and frames do not change.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on another link 
[Android animation with multiple jpeg files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004824/android-animation-with-multiple-jpeg-files)

We need to set the animation file in anim folder, set it as source to the imageview, getdrawable instead of getResourceBackground and assign it to animationDrawable and start animation. With this all the layout attributes of the imageview will be maintained.

xml code

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/orderCards
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@anim/image_switcher_anim"/>
```

Java Code

```
imageAnim = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderCards);
                anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageAnim.getDrawable();
                imageAnim.post(run);

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            anim.start();
        }
    };
```